# How do I convert my bootstrap website into a drupal theme?

Tags: drupal, twitter-bootstrap-3, e-commerce

I made a bootstrap e-commerce website. I came to know that the Drupal CMS has all the feautures that I need to get things done in my website. The only thing that I need now is "How do I convert my site into a drupal theme"

I saw many tutorials which tell how to convert HTML into drupal theme, nut I am not sure how to integrate Bootstrap theme with it. Acquia might help, but I am not sure if it would be flexible enough?

Can someone tell me how do I convert my site, briefly, in steps?

Answer (score 1):

You can use drupal bootstrap theme as a base theme 
https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap
and then can create a sub theme in drupal.Create your own template files and add your html snippets there.For debugging while creating the theme use drupal theme developer module.
https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer

For more drupal theming have a look at documentation on drupal.org